# The Cask of Amontillado by Edgar Allen Poe

Tags: meaning, phrases

What is the meaning of the following phrase from ["The Cask of Amontillado" By Edgar Allan Poe?](http://xroads.virginia.edu/~hyper/POE/cask.html)

> A wrong is unredressed when retribution overtakes its redresser. It is equally unredressed when the avenger fails to make himself felt as such to him who has done the wrong.

Comment: If someone hurts you, and you try to get even by hurting him back, but he hurts you again for hurting him back, then you didn't get even.  Also, if someone cuts you off in traffic, then you follow him to his house and throw a brick through his window, but you forget to tie a message to the brick saying why you're getting even, it doesn't count.  You didn't get even.

Comment: @GregLee Will you put this as an answer so it can be determined. please include your research

Comment: No, sorry. ....

Comment: @GregLee May you explain why? I'm afraid I do not understand. Are you afraid of losing what you have gained?

Comment: I think this goes deeper. If retribution becomes the prime motive of the the redresser, the redresser will not right the wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sentence

> A wrong is unredressed when retribution overtakes its redresser.

may best be understood with the preceding sentence:

> I must not only punish but punish with impunity.

The narrator Montresor feels wronged by Fortunato and wishes *redress* for those wrongs done to him, i.e., he wishes compensation.  Which in Poe's tale takes the form of Montresor killing Fortunato.  But Montresor wants to get away with the murder -- he won't feel things are set right if he is punished in turn for the punishment he inflicts on his victim.

When Montresor says

> It is equally unredressed when the avenger fails to make himself felt
>   as such to him who has done the wrong.

he means that he (as the avenger) won't feel things are set right if the victim doesn't realize who's doing the punishing.  It's not enough for Montresor to kill Fortunato; Fortunato must understand that it is Montresor who is killing him.

Answer (score 0):

"A wrong is unredressed when retribution overtakes it's redresser."

Or in other words...

A wrong worsens when vengeance overtakes the victim.

"It is equally unredressed when the avenger fails to make himself felt as such to him who has done the wrong."

Or in other words...

A wrong also worsens when the avenger fails at satisfying their thirst for revenge or vengeance.